# Is the FAA Medical Exam an IRS Medical Expense?

Tags: usa, medical

Does the FAA Medical Exam for a medical certificate qualify as a Medical Expense per [IRS Publication 502](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p502.pdf) (thus allowing one to deduct the expense, or utilize a Health Savings Account (HSA)/Flexible Spending Account (FSA))?

One possible way to have the medical exam qualify as a medical expense would be to have a standard physical exam and the FAA medical exam together (which might also let you claim it with your [health insurance](http://www.crissmanfamilypractice.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/site.content/type/89593/custom/1.cfm)).

Is this interpretation correct or consistent with your experience?

Comment: Your question title is asking about the IRS, i.e. is the medical tax-deductible? But the AME quote is about claiming the costs from your insurance company. Those are totally different things. I assume you're asking about the tax issue because that's - in theory - the same for everyone, whereas the insurance question depends on your policy so it isn't really answerable. Is that correct? If so, I suggest you remove the AME quote to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question to reflect the primary focus (is it qualified medical expense for the IRS?) but also kept the pointer to billing insurance (for those interested).

Comment: FWIW, during the 30 years I was flying professionally, I always claimed it as a job related expense, and I was never audited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can pay for one with an HSA or FSA, then yes, [physical exams are eligible expenses](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p502/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000179002), though consult with your insurance provider first if they are covered by your plan.

> **Physical Examination**
>
> You can include in medical expenses the amount you pay for an annual physical examination and diagnostic tests by a physician. You do not have to be ill at the time of the examination.

If you're looking to add it to a list of itemized deductions, as Pondlife explained, it generally has to be [business- or workplace related](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p535/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000208606).  If you are a professional pilot, then this is deductible.

> **What Can I Deduct?**
>
> To be deductible, a business expense must be both ordinary and necessary. An ordinary expense is **one that is common and accepted in your industry**. A necessary expense is one that is helpful and appropriate for your trade or business. An expense does not have to be indispensable to be considered necessary.

Comment: i would keep in mind that it's inappropriate to exclude things twice - your hsa/fsa spending is already not taxed, as contributions made to it are already deductible, so you can't reduce your taxable income further by claiming an individual expense a second time.

Comment: For those without HSA/FSAs, you would be able to deduct the physical exam as a medical expense (provided that your total medical expenditure exceeds [10% of AGI](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc502.html) or 7.5% of AGI if you are over 65). Having an HSA/FSA means you don't have to worry whether you can deduct it or not: it would be paid for with pre-tax money already set aside for qualified medical expenses.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like if you're a professional pilot then [yes](http://www.aviationtaxglossary.com/employee_business_expenses/) (it's an unavoidable expense for your job). Otherwise, [no](http://www.ustaxcourt.gov/InOpHistoric/PetersonMemo.Lauber.TCM.WPD.pdf) (probably, see disclaimer below):

> Flights in the first three categories [including for FAA medicals] were clearly personal,
>   reflecting petitioner’s family or personal obligations, personal
>   finances, or love of flying

And [this](http://www.aopa.org/Pilot-Resources/PIC-archive/Aircraft-Ownership/Business-Justification-Flight-Training-Expenses) from AOPA:

> The first thing you'll notice in these regulations is that your flight
>   training expenses will be deductible only if they are trade or
>   business related. Therefore, if your flying is purely personal in
>   nature, you will not be able to take a tax deduction for flight
>   training expenses.

Admittedly that talks about training, not medical expenses, but a medical is required unless you're a sport pilot so it seems to apply.

Disclaimer: I'm not a tax attorney, if you want an answer that will stand up in court than ask someone who is :-)

Comment: Your first link says that it could be written off as a business expense, *not* as a medical expense. Also, in the case you mention, petitioner claimed the medical exams as business expenses (though I suspect if he thought he had a chance he would have claimed it as medical, so you might have a point there).